# asp.net 3.5 Authorization works on localhost, on test (IIS6) Authorization Location part is ignored

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

In my webapplication i've made a subfolder named 'System'. In the root of the web application authorization is setup like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="43200" path="/" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

In the 'System' folder, i've added a web.config file with the following:

```
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="administrator" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>


  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="partner" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

When running this webapp locally (win7 x64, VS2010), these acces rules are honoured. Meaning, the Partner-role *can* access 'System' folder, only accessing Default.aspx.

When I publish my website on a win2k3 machine with IIS 6.0, the Partner role gets redirected to the logon page. When I view the .NET configuration settings in IIS6 on the 'System/Default.aspx', the role 'Partner' is Allowed, but somehow it's ignored.

Any one has a clue?